# Issue verifying proxy contract with linked library

Tags: etherscan, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, verify

I am experiencing a weird issue when verifying a Proxy Contract on Etherscan. I am using `hardhat`, `@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades`, and `@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan`.

**The issue**

> Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: Unable to process the
> standard-input-json you uploaded

**Here's my deployment logic**

```
let Helper_Functions = await ethers.getContractFactory("Helper_Functions");
Helper_Functions = await Helper_Functions.deploy();
await Helper_Functions.deployTransaction.wait();

let Production_Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Production_Contract", {
    libraries: {
      Helper_Functions: Helper_Functions.address
    }
});

Production_Contract = await upgrades.deployProxy(Production_Contract, [], { kind: 'transparent', unsafeAllowLinkedLibraries: true });

await Production_Contract.deployTransaction.wait();

await hre.run("verify:verify", {
    address: Production_Contract.address,
    constructorArguments: [],
    libraries: {
      Helper_Functions: Helper_Functions.address
    }
});
```

**What I have already tried**

1. Verifying manually from CLI using `npx hardhat verify --network sepolia contract_address`
2. Changing contract proxy type, basically removing `kind: 'transparent'`
3. Flattening the contract and uploading it as a file to Etherscan

Somehow I always get the same result. I'm guessing there is something weird about my particular setup since I have a linked library which is unusual for proxy contracts?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out after hours of trying! I set the optimizer runs quite high (literally at the max value of 4294967295) and that was somehow interfering. So if you encounter this issue are are sure of your code and deployment logic, it's quite likely something like that in your config.

Answer (score 0):

That is really strange:

The only issue I could imagine with an optimizer number set high is the contract size exceeding 24Kb, but Hardhat should have given you waring about that.

Could you maybe again set the optimizer value high: **4294967295**

Then run `npx hardhat compile` and see if there is a warning about contract size.

Comment: I could be wrong but I suspect the high value of runs is an issue because I read somewhere etherscan allocates a max run time for compiling on their end to verify contracts. The error message I get is weird though if that's the case. 

I don't have contract sizing issues because I use the `hardhat-contract-sizer` plugin to optimize and stay below 24kb. When I set to 200 runs I'm able to verify fine, so the number of runs in the optimizer is for sure the issue. Also more runs usually means smaller contract size. Going to try to see the max runs they accept

Comment: Also the contract compiles and deploys without issue, which wouldn't be possible if it was too large

Comment: Larger numbers or runs in optimizer can give you bigger contracts,  because it's optimizing for use, not deployment.  I also used huge numbers in optimizer (max size of 2^32-1) and I had no issues. That is why I am surprised by your error.